# Table x has no column y error

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

Can anybody help me find the problem.Everything runs fine,until I try to add something on the database.This is the error log.

```
10-24 03:55:21.625: E/SQLiteLog(924): (1) table contacts has no column named breed
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924): Error inserting breed=null weight=null notes=null dateoffertilization=null earring=null milkproduction=null age=null
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named breed (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(breed,weight,notes,dateoffertilization,earring,milkproduction,age) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at farm.admin.DatabaseHandler.Add_Contact(DatabaseHandler.java:75)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at farm.admin.Add_Update_User$1.onClick(Add_Update_User.java:146)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-24 03:55:21.645: E/SQLiteDatabase(924):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is the code.

```
package farm.admin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_EARRING = "earring";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
private static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
private static final String KEY_MILKPRODUCTION = "milkproduction";
private static final String KEY_BREED = "breed";
private static final String KEY_DATEOFFERTILIZATION = "dateoffertilization";
private static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
private final ArrayList<Contact> contact_list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_EARRING + " TEXT," + KEY_AGE + " TEXT," + KEY_WEIGHT + " TEXT" + KEY_MILKPRODUCTION + " TEXT," + KEY_BREED + " TEXT," + KEY_DATEOFFERTILIZATION + " TEXT" + KEY_NOTES + " TEXT," + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// Drop older table if existed
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

// Create tables again
onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
public void Add_Contact(Contact contact) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_EARRING, contact.getEarring()); // Contact earring
values.put(KEY_AGE, contact.getAge()); // Contact age
values.put(KEY_WEIGHT, contact.getWeight()); // Contact weight
values.put(KEY_MILKPRODUCTION, contact.getMilkproduction()); // Contact milkprodcution
values.put(KEY_BREED, contact.getBreed()); // Contact breed
values.put(KEY_DATEOFFERTILIZATION, contact.getDateoffertilization()); // Contact date
values.put(KEY_NOTES, contact.getNotes()); // Contact notes
// Inserting Row
db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact Get_Contact(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
    KEY_EARRING, KEY_AGE, KEY_WEIGHT,KEY_MILKPRODUCTION, KEY_BREED, KEY_DATEOFFERTILIZATION, KEY_NOTES }, KEY_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7));
// return contact
cursor.close();
db.close();

return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public ArrayList<Contact> Get_Contacts() {
try {
    contact_list.clear();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setEarring(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
        contact.setWeight(cursor.getString(3));
        contact.setMilkproduction(cursor.getString(4));
        contact.setBreed(cursor.getString(5));
        contact.setDateoffertilization(cursor.getString(6));
        contact.setNotes(cursor.getString(7));
        // Adding contact to list
        contact_list.add(contact);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return contact_list;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
}

return contact_list;
}

// Updating single contact
public int Update_Contact(Contact contact) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_EARRING, contact.getEarring());
values.put(KEY_AGE, contact.getAge());
values.put(KEY_WEIGHT, contact.getWeight());
values.put(KEY_MILKPRODUCTION, contact.getMilkproduction());
values.put(KEY_BREED, contact.getBreed());
values.put(KEY_DATEOFFERTILIZATION, contact.getDateoffertilization());
values.put(KEY_NOTES, contact.getNotes());

// updating row
return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void Delete_Contact(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
db.close();
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int Get_Total_Contacts() {
String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
cursor.close();

// return count
return cursor.getCount();
}
```

}

If anyone could help me point the problem,would be great.I am sure that I messed up something on table creation.Maybe something is wrong with commas or spaces.

EDIT1

After some suggestions I tried adding some missing commas , removing the last and reinstall the app.Now after I tried to add something ,the app crashed and I always get the message "unfortunately,the app stopped working" or something like this.But I get a new fatal exception.Here's the log.

```
10-24 06:32:40.521: D/dalvikvm(837): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 5% free 2938K/3068K, paused 28ms, total 30ms
10-24 06:32:40.561: D/AndroidRuntime(837): Shutting down VM
10-24 06:32:40.571: W/dalvikvm(837): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at farm.admin.Main_Screen$Contact_Adapter.getView(Main_Screen.java:157)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-24 06:32:40.581: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you changed the code for creating table after running app once, then clean the data, and rerun the application.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am new,so maybe you can tell me how to do this please?

Comment: The NPE in farm.admin.Main_Screen$Contact_Adapter.getView() is a separate problem. If you need help with it, post another question with relevant code from your adapter.

Comment: ok,I did it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564405/farm-admin-main-screencontact-adapter-getview-fatal-exceptioneclipeandroi

Comment: Your question has already been answered. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_EARRING + " TEXT," + KEY_AGE + " TEXT," + KEY_WEIGHT + " TEXT" + KEY_MILKPRODUCTION + " TEXT," + KEY_BREED + " TEXT," + KEY_DATEOFFERTILIZATION + " TEXT" + KEY_NOTES + " TEXT," + ")";
```

There are some `,` missing between column specifications. E.g. after `weight` and  ?`dateoffertilization`. Also no need for a `,` after the last column spec.

After changing the schema here, either bump up `DATABASE_VERSION` or just wipe your application's data to make sure the table creation runs again.

Comment: I fixed the commas,but the problem is still here.I read this "wipe old application",almost everywhere.Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: @hhayf Either go to app manager -> your app -> app info and select "Clear data" or just uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I did your suggestions and the program now progresses,but a new problem occured.I updated my topic above.